# Retaining leading zeros when typecasting int to string

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, valueerror

I am writing a code in which I break a number into 2 parts, left half and right half.

For example 5105 is broken into 51 and 05.

For this I write simple code as follows

```
number_xs= str(x)
```

Now the problem is when pass 05 into x. number_xs is only 5. I want it to be 05 as I convert that 0 back to int and pass it somewhere else in code. Right now it takes a bank and throws me an error 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Further note that I wont know in advance that it is one zero or 2 or 3. say number can be 0075 and want 2 zeros to be there when I typecast.

Further posting portion of code

```
def ABC (x):
    # Dividing number into 2 equal half   
    number_xs= str(x)
    l_x=len(number_xs)/2
    a,b=number_xs[:l_x],number_xs[l_x:]
    print a
    a=int(a)
    b=int(b)
    #print a
    #print b
```

Thanks in advance
Aashish

Comment: What if there's an odd number of digits, like in `123`?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] please? `int('05')` should not throw an error.  It's just overall very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ Aran Fey I am not expecting odd number of digits.

Comment: I'm confused. Is your input a number or a string? There's no difference between the numbers `0075` and `75`, so how can you possibly know where to split? (Well, except `0075` is a syntax error)

Comment: @ user3483203, when i take 05 and type caste into string I expect it to be '05'. Then I want to take first half of string i.e 0 and typecaste it back to integer i.e 0 and use that zero. But since typcasting 05 into string gives me '5'. 0 is blank i.e '' and typcasting int () gives value error

Comment: @ Aron Fey: My input is a number. My intention is to divide that even digit number into 2 parts. and use it as integer. So I convert number into string. divide the string by array indexing and then convert substring back to integer

Comment: Your question is just overall unclear.  You provide a single line of code which really shows us nothing, and then talk about errors which we can't reproduce because you have not shown what else you are doing.

Comment: My apologies. let me give you more of the code.

Comment: I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: You have a lot of indentation errors.

Comment: I dont see any indentation error at my part. All i see is ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10, which I figured would be beacause when I type cast 05 to string I get only 5 instead of 05. Perhaps my approach to divide a decimal number into 2 halves, left and right is not right.

Comment: If you want to treat leading zeroes as significant, you're not dealing with numbers. Stick to strings throughout.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Yes!!. I that would work. I figured I needed integer value only while doing end computation. So In the above code I passed x as string only. And took input as string rather than number.

Answer (score 0):

you want the length of your string to be always even

```
def ABC (x):
    # Dividing number into 2 equal half
    number_xs = str(x)
    if len(number_xs)%2 == 1:
        number_xs = '0'+number_xs
    l_x=len(number_xs)/2
    a,b=number_xs[:l_x],number_xs[l_x:]
    print('str', a, b)
    a=int(a)
    b=int(b)
    print('int', a, b)
```